# How to print out an function variable at HTML in python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am a self-learner and a beginner, searched a lot but maybe have lack of searching. I am scraping some values from two web sites and I want o compare them with an HTML output. Each web pages, I am combinin two class'es and gettin into a list. But when making an output with HTML I don't want all list to print. So I made function to choose any keywords to print. When I want to print out that function, It turns out 'None' at HTML output but it turns what I wanted on console. So how to show that special list?

OS= Windows , Python3.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import datetime
import os
import webbrowser

carf_meySayf = requests.get('https://www.carrefoursa.com/tr/tr/meyve/c/1015?show=All').text
carf_soup = BeautifulSoup(carf_meySayf, 'lxml')

#spans
carf_name_span = carf_soup.find_all('span', {'class' : 'item-name'})
carf_price_span = carf_soup.find_all('span', {'class' : 'item-price'})


#spans to list
carf_name_list = [span.get_text() for span in carf_name_span]
carf_price_list = [span.get_text() for span in carf_price_span]

#combine lists
carf_mey_all = [carf_name_list +' = ' + carf_price_list for carf_name_list, carf_price_list in zip(carf_name_list, carf_price_list)]



#Function to choose and print special product

def test(namelist,product):
    for i in namelist:
        if product in i:
            print(i)


a = test(carf_mey_all,'Muz')


# Date
date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

# HTML part
html_str = """
<html>
    <title>Listeler</title>
        <h2>Tarih: %s</h2>
        <h3>Product & Shop List</h3>
            <table style="width:100%%">
                <tr>
                    <th>Carrefour</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                 %s
                </tr>
</html>
""" 

whole = html_str %(date,a)


Html_file= open("Meyve.html","w")
Html_file.write(whole)
Html_file.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the method `test()` must have `return` value, for example

```
def test(namelist,product):
    results = ''
    for i in namelist:
        if product in i:
            print(i)
            results += '<td>%s</td>\n' % i
    return results
```

`Meyve.html` results:

```
<html>
<title>Listeler</title>
<h2>Tarih: 2018-12-29 07:34:00</h2>
<h3>Product & Shop List</h3>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Carrefour</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Muz = 6,99 TL</td>
    <td>İthal Muz = 12,90 TL</td>
    <td>Paket Yerli Muz = 9,99 TL</td>
  </tr>

</html>
```

note: to be valid html you need to add `<body></body>`

Comment: Thanks so much for a great and fast response

Comment: you're welcome. if there is answer solved your problem please mark it as correct

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `test()` function isn't explicitly returning anything, so it is implicitly returning `None`.
To fix this, `test()` should accumulate the text it wants to return (i.e, by building a list or string) and return a string containing the text you want to insert into `html_str`.